# how to dynamically specify data type while creating the table in MS access using Java

Tags: java, database, jdbc

My application is extracting the data from excel sheet. I am storing the value and type of the data from the sheet into the ArrayList. ie., If my excel sheet consists of employee data, i will retrive [ Employee name, String] [ Employee id, number] and so on.. So i have to create a table with these names and with their respective data types. So how could i dynamically specify the data types for the attributes in the table. I am using JDBC,MS Access..

Comment: Could you explain what you do with jdbc in this context?

Comment: I am retriving the data from the Excel sheet using java-JExcel API and i am creating the table with the column names which i had retrived it from the first cell columns from the excel sheet. ie., Employee name,Employee id, salary etc., Then i have to specify its type which i had acquired from the JExcel API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you read your data in a String, and for every value do `String.matches(regex)` to find out the datatype. For example do value.matches("\d"), if it mathces, then instantiate an Integer like, `new Integer(value)`. Now, you should be able to add this new integer object into your `List`.

I hope you will be able to see how to go further. Check the instanceof or something while creating the table in the database.

Answer (score 0):

For each different data type, use a different class. You can either use the default java classes like String or Integer, or make your own depending on your further requirements. You can store all these classes in your ArrayList.

When retrieving your data, check which class is used and handle it appropriately.

Comment: That is ok, but i want to write a query to create a table with the dynamic data (Column name and type).